# How do I get a pdf based on these acceptance-rejection simulation criteria?

Tags: probability, data-transformation

I have been given an algorithm to generate a random variable $Y$, as follows:

- $X=-\ln(Z)$
- If $X>2$ then $Y=X-2$, otherwise reject.

I'm then asked to find the pdf and cdf of $Y$.

Can anyone tell me how to read this?

I know in theory what both are but I'm finding it difficult to infer them from problems like this.

Comment: I think you will need to tell us what $Z$ is first.

Comment: Is $Z$ intended to be uniform on $(0,1)$? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

If $Z$ is intended to be standard uniform, you can use elementary probability arguments in terms of the cdf to derive that $-\ln Z$ is standard exponential (the details of which arguments I leave to you).

The distribution is then truncated to be $>2$ and then shifted by subtracting 2. For the [truncation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution#Definition) you just need to consider the effect on the density:

[image]

Or you can get there from the [memoryless property of the exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness#Continuous_memorylessness).